# Какое явление языка отражено в предложениях?

Tags: языкознание

Вопрос школьной олимпиады. Какое явление в языке отражают данные предложения:

- «В то время был ещё  жених её супруг» (А. С. Пушкин);
- «Терпи казак — атаман будешь» (Н. В. Гоголь);
- «Он решил, что женитьба на Элен была бы несчастье» (Л. Толстой).

Comment: Я думаю, ученица ответила верно, но ей не засчитали ответ. Хочу спросить, как вы думаете, какой ответ будет верным (или верный?)

Comment: Самый общий ответ : существительное в составном именном сказуемом.

Comment: Она ответила гораздо больше, и то не засчитали

Comment: А может, имели в виду устаревшее управление? Управление - это тоже явление грамматики. Может, поэтому и дали все примеры со значением непостоянного признака , но с использованием нулевого окончания. Но тогда она это описала, почему не зачли? Слова этого не увидели?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что архаизация.
[здесь](http://www.nkj.ru/archive/articles/4001/)

Comment: В статье по ссылке говорится, что во времена, когда писались цитируемые строки, были общеупотребительны обе формы (и творительный, и именительный падеж). Следовательно, в примерах никакого *явления языка* не отражается. Ну, разве что, **вариативность**.

Comment: Девочка ответила, что это использование старых форм составного именного сказуемого со связкой быть.По-моему, это то же самое, что архаизация, термин этот в учебниках отсутствует, она его знать не могла. Думаю, это несправедливо. А может, они хотели получить ответ "синонимия", если требовали назвать явление? Кто знает, что у них там в ключах было... Это ведь грамматическая синонимия: им.пад. - постоянный признак, творит. пад. - временный,непостоянный: Он был артист - "всегда и во всём". Он был артистом - сейчас он артист по профессии.Но тогда они должны были дать примеры и с творит. падежом.

Comment: >Это ведь грамматическая синонимия:  
  
Разве? Вроде значения-то разные...

>использование старых форм составного именного сказуемого со связкой быть 

Использование - явление? не, я не спорю, я думаю, какого рожна хотели авторы.

Кстати, а который класс у олимпийцев?

Comment: Где же разные? Разные оттенки семантики, а грамматическое - одно - сост. именное сказуемое, только имя в разных падежах, что это ещё, как не грамматическая синонимия?

Comment: Насчёт ИМЕНИТЕЛЬНОГО ПРЕДИКАТИВА - я не сразу поняла, потому что есть термин именно в этом виде, а именительный предикативный и творительный предикативный - это опять-таки не для школьников. Вы правы,я тоже не пойму, что они хотели от школьников. Вероятно, термин попроще - может, всё же синонимия?

Comment: >Насчёт ИМЕНИТЕЛЬНОГО ПРЕДИКАТИВА - я не сразу поняла, потому что есть термин именно в этом виде  
  
Да вроде бы я не отступил от терминологии.
Именительный темы, именительный представления. Значит "именительный предикатива" должен быть вполне понятен. Мне даже в голову не пришло, что он должен быть "именительным **предикативным**" - и только им.

Comment: Под функционально-грамматической синонимией вслед за
Т. С. Сорокиной понимаем  «однотипные или разноструктурные грамматические единицы как одного,  так и различных уровней,  выполняющих одну и ту же семантическую функцию при необязательной лексической тождественности» Здесь грамматическая синонимия падежных форм именит. и творит. падежа в сост. именном сказуемом. Только дан один падеж, если бы имелось в виду это, наверно, дали бы и примеры с творительным. Я не знаю, что они имели в виду.

Comment: >>>«однотипные ... при необязательной лексической тождественности»  
  
Тогда - да. Принято. Просто терминология весьма размыта (это по разным источникам), я не сталкивался с такой формулировкой, понимая все по рабоче-крестьянски.  
Но возвращаясь к нашим баранам. Пусть даже в такой формулировке. *Грамматическая синонимия - явление?*

Comment: Вопрос разобрали по косточкам, а однозначного варианта ответа так и нет.
Пусть девочка спросит у своего учителя по русскому. Мы все хотим знать точный ответ!!!

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что "явление" отражает прежде всего неграмотно сформулированный вопрос. 
Обидно когда "правильный" ответ зависит от способности ученика понять логику автора вопроса, а не от объективного умения мыслить.

Вообще-то эта форма называется [*именительным предикатива*](http://linguistic-dictionary.info/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/1286/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)... Неужели это имелось в виду?

Ну да ладно. 
Я против определения "явления" как архаизма. Во-первых, архаизм - это использование в речи устаревших форм, а для писателей это была грамматика вполне им современная. Во-вторых, как вообще может текст отражать что-либо, произошедшее сто лет спустя после его, текста, написания?! Ну добро бы еще было сказано, что явление историческое или к историческоq грамматике относящееся. Так ведь нет...

А можно вообще узнать как это задание оформлять положено? Как в ЕГЭ? Вписывать в  клеточки одно-единственое слово?

//-----
Я сделал механическую ошибку, назвав предикатив партитивом. Быстро исправил, не думал, что мой промах успеют зафиксировать. Прошу простить великодушно.  остальное - в силе.

Comment: Вопрос звучал именно так, как я поставила, можно было описать это явление, объяснить, никаких клеточек не было, места было достаточно.Ответа мы теперь не узнаем. Ей поставили 0, значит, неверно. Вот я и хочу узнать, что же верно. Термины в олимпиадах должны быть из программы, никаких партитивов быть не может. Если они имели в виду вариативность, как говорит stopkran,или, как я подумала, синонимию,были бы и вторые варианты, а здесь только именительный падеж. Так какое же явление?

Comment: "Именительный предикатива" - такого понятия в русском языке не знаю, в прибалтийских, может, в эсперанто, есть. Подскажите, где поискать о  нём в русском. А партитивный и вовсе - второй родительный,отделительный (стакан чаю), а не творительный, как у нас.

Comment: Предикатив - это неизменяемое слово в значении сказуемого, категория состояния, при чём здесь  изменяемое существительное?

Comment: >Подскажите, где поискать о нём в русском.  
  
У Розенталя, как всегда. Я же ссылку дал в ответе.
Ну вот [еще раз][1].

>это неизменяемое слово в значении сказуемого  
  
Это школьное, весьма зауженное представление.

[1]: http://linguistic-dictionary.info/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/1286/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Comment: Насчёт архаизации, думаю, это возможно, потому что формы именительного в составном сказуемом были в древнерусском языке, в "Слове о полку Игореве " их много, в 19 веке эта форма уже считалась устаревшей нормой, чаще употреблялся творительный, а в книжной речи - как что-то народно-поэтическое, потому что все старые формы закреплялись в говорах и оставались часто в разговорной речи. Может, это имелось в виду - явление закрепления разговорных форм как нормы?  Вернее, получается опять возврат к архаичной морфологии, снова пришли к архаике.

Comment: >это неизменяемое слово в значении сказуемого  
  
Это школьное, весьма зауженное представление. Впрочем, это не здесь выяснять. Мы об одном и том же говорим. Просто я думаю над вопросом как он поставлен. Как **назвать это явление**.

>Насчёт архаизации, думаю, это возможно,  
  
Ну да, согласен, в какой-то степени формы эти были устаревающими уже тогда, но это как же надо исхитриться, чтобы у школьников такое спросить?!

Answer (score 0):

В этих предложениях, может быть, отражено употребление формы именительного падежа в функции присвязочной части составного именного сказуемого. Германн был сын обрусевшего немца (Пушкин). При связке был, будет именительный предикативный указывает на существенный признак предмета, обозначенного подлежащим, выражает его оценку. Новое здание была больница. Его мать была сама доброта. Именительный падеж указывает также на устойчивый, постоянный признак (ср. творительный предикативный, обычно выражающий временный признак). Он был крестьянин (Гл. Успенский).

ЯВЛЕНИЕ, -я, ср. 1. смотрите явиться. 2. В философии: проявление, выражение сущности, то, в чём она обнаруживается. Явление и сущность. 3. Вообще всякое обнаруживаемое проявление чего-нибудь Физическое явление Явления природы. Социальные явления. 4. Событие, случай.

Странное, загадочное явление 5. В пьесе: часть акта, в к-рой состав действующих лиц не меняется.

1. СЛУЧАЙ.

ЯВЛЕНИЕ - СЛУЧАЙ УПОТРЕБЛЕНИЯ ФОРМЫ ИМ. ПАДЕЖА В функции присвязочной части составного именного сказуемого.

3.ЯВЛЕНИЕ - Обнаруживаемое проявление УПОТРЕБЛЕНИЯ ФОРМЫ ИМ. ПАДЕЖА В функции присвязочной части составного именного сказуемого.

Comment: Вопрос: какое явление языка отражено? Использование чего-то - не явление. И , к тому же, об этом речь была - не засчитали.